# Changing rock paper scissors game from alert to the DOM

Tags: javascript

I have been coding javascript for a little over 2 weeks and I am expirementing with a rock paper scissors game. I got the game to work relatively good using the alert box but now I want to move it from the alert to something on screen. I have created a simple table that will keep track of the users guess as well as the computer guess and also keep track of scores.

currently I have the player and computer guess showing up in the correct area but it only shows for the last round. The game goes for 3 rounds and it currently only shows the guesses from the last round.

```js
const uguess = document.querySelector('#uguess')
const cguess = document.querySelector('#cguess')
const uscore = document.querySelector('#uscore')
const cscore = document.querySelector('#cscore')


let button = document.getElementById('btn')

button.addEventListener('click', playerGuess);
let numTries = 0
let userScore = 0
let computerScore = 0

function playerGuess() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const arr = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    let randomIndex = arr[number];

    numTries += 1
    console.log(randomIndex);
    const guess = prompt("Lets play rock, paper, scissors" + "\nWhat is your pick?");

    uguess.innerHTML = guess;
    cguess.innerHTML = randomIndex;

    checkGuess(guess, randomIndex)

  }

  if (userScore > computerScore) {
    alert('Your score was ' + userScore + '\n\n My score was ' + computerScore + '\n\nYou Win!')
  } else {
    alert('Your score was ' + userScore + '\n\n My score was ' + computerScore + '\n\nI Win!')
  }
}



function checkGuess(guess, randomIndex) {

  let playerScore = 0

  if (guess === randomIndex) {
    alert('My guess Was: ' + randomIndex + ' It Looks Like We Tied' + 'You have tried ' + numTries + 'times');

  } else if (guess === 'rock' && randomIndex === 'paper') {
    alert('My guess was: ' + randomIndex + ' \nI win!' + 'You have tried ' + numTries + 'times')
    computerScore++


  } else if (guess === 'rock' && randomIndex === 'scissors') {
    alert('My guess was: ' + randomIndex + '\nYou win!' + 'You have tried ' + numTries + 'times')

    userScore++

  } else if (guess === 'paper' && randomIndex === 'rock') {
    alert('My guess was: ' + randomIndex + ' \nYou win!' + 'You have tried ' + numTries + 'times')
    userScore++

  } else if (guess === 'paper' && randomIndex === 'scissors') {
    alert('My guess was: ' + randomIndex + '\nI win!' + 'You have tried ' + numTries + 'times')
    computerScore++

  } else if (guess === 'scissors' && randomIndex === 'paper') {
    alert('My guess was: ' + randomIndex + ' \nYou win!' + 'You have tried ' + numTries + 'times')
    userScore++

  } else if (guess === 'scissors' && randomIndex === 'rock') {
    alert('My guess was: ' + randomIndex + ' \nI win!' + 'You have tried ' + numTries + 'times')
    computerScore++

  }


}
```

```html
<h1>Rock Paper Scissors Game</h1>
<div id='gametable'>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Computer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Guess</td>
      <td id='uguess'></td>
      <td id='cguess'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Score</td>
      <td id='uscore'></td>
      <td id='cscore'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button id='btn' type=b utton>Start Game</button>
```

I am very new so hopefully the quality of the code isn't too much of a problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is primarily about adding rows/cells to a table. Please look for existing solutions before posting a question. Google something like "js add row to table site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Just adding a little bit from what @ChrisG says, if you're trying just to add more row(s) to a table and not bothering about using library may be you can just start with jquery and using `append` or something. You can learn more about jquery [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

Comment: Ok thanks for the help guys. I will try that.